# Is there a name for the fact that, in fiction (tv or otherwise), actions have consequences in the next episodes?

Tags: single-word-requests

This might sound silly, but I can't get the question out of my head.

In some TV shows a person may die in one episode and come back the next - actions in one episode do not seem to have consequences in the next.
In other shows, what's done is done and scenarists can't resurrect people - worlds have more coherence.

Is there a specific term that captures this difference?
I've thought about realist vs fantastic but it seemed a bit broad.

Comment: _Continuity_ is the general term; there's a continuity person for anything that's shot out of order, for instance, to make sure that the magazine on the coffee table in this scene is in the same place it was left at the end of the last scene, which was filmed 3 days ago. As for foreshadowing, there's the dramatic term _the McGuffin_, which refers to the thing everyone is searching for in many plays -- the holy grail, the clue to the murder, the smoking gun, the Eye of the Idol, etc.

Comment: The better shows stay *in universe*, meaning the (fictional) universe for that show is consistent, and things can be explained.

Comment: Are we talking about the difference between a *serial* where the plot continues from one episode to the next, and a *series* where each episode is self-contained?

Comment: Ah, but killing Kenny *is* continuity!

Comment: In Abbot's Flatland universe it would be "unreal" for a two-dimensional character to "rise above the plane of his existence." In Montgomery's Avonlea universe it would be unreal for Matthew Cuthbert to come back to life. In Lewis's Narnia universe it is perfectly real for Jadis to be killed by Aslan at the end of The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe, but then reappear in Prince Caspian, and again in The Voyage of the Dawn Treader. Three fictional universes with different realities.

Comment: O my God! This about South Park!...You badtards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would describe a show that maintains a realistic flow of events as having 'Continuity' and one where events don't have persistent consequences as lacking continuity.

con·ti·nu·i·ty
ˌkäntəˈn(y)o͞oədē/
noun
1.
the unbroken and consistent existence or operation of something over a period of time.
"pension rights accruing through continuity of employment"
synonyms:   continuousness, uninterruptedness, flow, progression
"a breakdown in the continuity of care"
a state of stability and the absence of disruption.
"they have provided the country with a measure of continuity"
a connection or line of development with no sharp breaks.
plural noun: continuities
"they used the same style of masonry to provide continuity between new and old"
synonyms:   continuousness, uninterruptedness, flow, progression
"a breakdown in the continuity of care"

2.
the maintenance of continuous action and self-consistent detail in the various scenes of a movie or broadcast.
"a continuity error"

Comment: That definition of continuity in cinema does not **necessarily** apply to the phenomenon described by the OP if the fictional universe of the film permits a certain kind of discontinuity.

Comment: @ScotM Could you elaborate on that statement?

Comment: See my comment under the question.

Comment: Definition 2 refers to "self consistent detail". I take "self consistent" to mean that a universe needs only to adhere to it's own rules, and not the rules of other universes.

Comment: We find ourselves in a Groundhog Day conundrum. If the fictional universe does not require *persistent consequences*, it does not lack continuity if *events don't have persistent consequences*. :)

Comment: In the show "South park" the first several seasons have a character who dies every episode but appears in subsequent episodes with no mention of his frequent deaths. We could take this to still maintain continuity if we assumed that the rules of that universe involved daily reincarnation... but at the same time death is discussed, it is known to exist in that universe. For some unmentioned reason this rule is broken, this is the breaking of continuity.

Comment: John Lawler gave the answer 'continuity' in a comment; repeating others' submissions isn't appropriate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Excuse me?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I entered the only existing answer and it in no way plagiarized the comment by JohnLawler. The comment section is not the place for answers. My answer was appropriate in every way. Continuity was the obvious answer. You're expression of a silly qualm isn't appropriate.

Comment: He offered the term 'continuity'. An hour later, so did you. You didn't even acknowledge the fact that J Lawler had first come up with the term in this thread. In what way isn't that 'the practice of taking someone else's work or ideas and passing them off as one's own.'? Or didn't you even bother to check?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think I'll just decline to engage with you from now on. All the best.

Comment: **Continuity** describes the difference in the OP, but the opening sentence of this answer belies the connection. Kenny died over and over for five years, returning in the next episode **without explanation**, because the **fantasy universe** of the program permits it: the *persistent consequences* of Kenny's death were **irrelevant** in his universe. When they didn't bring him back, the **lack of continuity** provoked some fans to boycott the program, compelling the writers to bring him back. Dave's answer has conflated *continuity* and *reality*! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenny_McCormick

Comment: That is a comment and not an answer...In regards to your claims: The magical nature of Kenny's resurrection wasn't retconned into the lore of the show until season 4, until that point his resurrections were a breaking of continuity.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the term ***[willing suspension of disbelief](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/suspension+of+disbelief)*** reconciles the ***difference*** between *realistic* television programs where:

> worlds have more coherence

and *fantastic* television programs where:

> actions in one episode do not seem to have consequences in the next

[Samuel Taylor Coleridge](https://notes.utk.edu/Bio/greenberg.nsf/0/aa819a734ce9d34585256e0e00717ab4) suggested that authors could induce the reader to suspend judgement concerning the implausibility of their narrative:

> transfer from our inward nature a **human interest** and a **semblance of
>   truth** sufficient to procure for these shadows of **imagination** that
>   ***willing suspension of disbelief*** for the moment, which constitutes poetic faith.
>
> *Biographia Literaria*

Some television programs create a *[fictional universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictional_universe)* that closely resembles the real world. *[Grey's Anatomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey%27s_Anatomy)* roughly approximates the world of surgical fellows, residents and attending physicians in the ***realistic fictional*** world of *Grey Sloan Memorial Hospital*. Some patients get better, others die, and from time to time the doctors bring their patients back from the dead. Except for the pace of action, everything is consistent with a real-world scenario. Fans *willingly suspend disbelief* of the pace to [follow the romantic intrigues of their favorite characters](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/greys-anatomy-romance-owen-amelia-740424).

Other programs create a fictional universe that departs immensely from the real world. For his first five seasons in the ***fantastic fictional*** world  of *South Park*, the cartoon character [***Kenny McCormick***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenny_McCormick) dies repeatedly:

> Prior to season six, Kenny died in almost every episode.[note 1] The
>   nature of the deaths was often gruesome and portrayed in a **comically
>   absurd fashion**,[8] and usually followed by Stan and Kyle respectively
>   yelling "Oh my God! They killed Kenny!" and "You bastard(s)!".[9]
>   Shortly afterward, rats would commonly appear and begin picking at his
>   corpse.[10] In a following episode, Kenny would reappear alive and
>   well, usually without any explanation. Most characters appear
>   oblivious or indifferent to the phenomenon, although occasionally one
>   will acknowledge an awareness of it.

The comical absurdity of Kenny's serial death and resurrection compelled such an intense ***human interest*** in Kenny that some fans erupted in protest when the writers refused to bring Kenny back after *Kenny Dies*:

> ["Kenny Dies"] was the one episode where [all the characters] cared [he was dying] for once. After that, we said, 'Why doesn't he just
>   stay dead?' And it was like, 'Okay, let's just do that.' It was that
>   easy of a decision. I think a lot of people probably haven't noticed.
>   I couldn't care less. I am so sick of that character. —Matt Stone,
>   from a 2002 article in the Knoxville News-Sentinel[13]
>
> ...fans were significantly
>   angered by Kenny's absence to threaten a boycott of the cable channel
>   Comedy Central, on which South Park is aired.

When Kenny came back at the end of the sixth season, the *fictional universe* of *South Park* still permitted Kenny to die and return again, but the writers shifted the ***human interest*** of the program away from Kenny to other characters.

> Nevertheless, Kenny returned from the year-long absence in the season
>   six finale "Red Sleigh Down", and has remained a main character since,
>   and has been given larger roles in episodes. His character no longer
>   dies each week, and has only been killed occasionally in episodes
>   following his return, at least once per season.[17] Only Season 12 and
>   17 do not feature a single death regarding Kenny.

Whether the *fictional universe* was *realistic* or *fantastic*, the *continuity* of the viewers ***human interest*** in the characters and their situation compelled them to *willingly suspend disbelief*. Overlooking the inconsistencies between their **real world** and the **fictional universe** of the story, they they simply enjoy the story.

Comment: I don't completely agree. Suspension of disbelief is when you ignore the fact the radioactive spiders give you superpowers. It is altering facts as we know in the real world. Suspension of disbelief is expected of the audience. But altering facts already established within the construct of the show/movie is a different thing.

Comment: *Continuity* and *suspension of disbelief* fit hand in glove for this question. Writers compel the suspension of disbelief by creating a continuity in characters and situations. This answer would be better if you gave specific examples of the fantastical universes you refer to. You should also connect it directly to the South Park issue, which seems to be the real rub.

Comment: @Tushar, that seems to be the essence of the OP. How can some programs permit fantastic fictional occurrences, while others stick to real world limitations? *Continuity* addresses **maintaining** the fictional universe, *retcon* addresses **repairing** breaches in continuity, *suspension of disbelief* addresses **creating** a fictional universe.

Comment: I donèt think this really fulfills the request but it is tangentially applicable and the accompanying information is impressively comprehensive so +1.

Answer (score 1):

'Continuity' seems to be the consensus for when actions have consequences from episode to episode.  TvTropes defines the opposite (e.g. Kenny dying in every episode of South Park) as **Status Quo is God**: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StatusQuoIsGod

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you are looking for, to explain the altered plotlines,  is:

> **retconning**

It is derived from retcon, which is short for retroactive continuity.

From wikipedia:

*[Retroactive continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroactive_continuity), or retcon for short, is the alteration of previously established facts in the continuity of a fictional work.*

Comment: I don't see the connection of *retcon* to the question. It seems that Kenny's serial death is part of the original plot line.

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of something as simple as the difference between *series* and *serial*.